# Deriving trigonometric expression for Prandtl-Meyer angle equation

Tags: trigonometry

The Prandtl-Meyer angle (θ) is a concept in supersonic flow specifically dedicated to compressible fluid dynamics or gas dynamics. The equation
$$d\left(\theta\right)=\pm\sqrt{M^2-1}\dfrac{dV}{V}$$
is not derived explicitly in the book "**Introduction to Numerical Techniques for Nonlinear Supersonic Flow**" by C. K. Chu. The book focuses on numerical techniques for solving nonlinear supersonic flow equations rather than providing a derivation for the Prandtl-Meyer angle equation.

As a result, I would like to derive the derivation of the above mentioned Prandtl-Meyer angle equation as prescribed in the book. I attached an image here from the textbook for your reference. Eq. 13.14 is the equation that needs to be derived.

**EqusFromTextBook:**

[image: EqusFromTextBook]

Here is what I have done.
$$\dfrac{d\left(V\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{ d\left(V\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}=\dfrac{ M^2\sin\left(\theta\right) \cos\left(\theta\right)\mp\sqrt{M^2-1}}{1-M^2\sin^2\left(\theta\right)} \tag{1}$$
After some algebraic manipulations, this reduces to,
$$d\theta=\mp\sqrt{M^2-1}\dfrac{dV}{V}, \tag{2}$$
where $\space d\theta\space$ is the Prandtl-Meyer angle.

LHS of (1) can be expanded as shown below.
$$\dfrac{d\left(V\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{ d\left(V\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}=
\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta\right)dV+V\sin\left(\theta\right)d\theta}{\cos\left(\theta\right)dV+V\cos\left(\theta\right)d\theta }
=\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta\right)\left(dV+Vd\theta\right)}{ \cos\left(\theta\right)\left(dV+Vd\theta\right)}=\tan\left(\theta\right)$$

**DerivingTheExpression:**

[image: DerivingTheExpression]

As shown above, the LHS of the equation $\dfrac{d\left(V\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{d\left(V\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}\space$ was reduced to $\space\tan\left(\theta\right)$. It seems that some more manipulations are needed to carry things forward. Can someone shed some light here? Thank you

Comment: Your expansion of the LHS of (1) is wrong. The correct expansion is, $$\dfrac{d\left(V\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{ d\left(V\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}=\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta\right)dV+V\cos\left(\theta\right)d\theta}{\cos\left(\theta\right)dV-V\sin\left(\theta\right)d\theta }.$$

Comment: Thank you @YNK for your comment. Yes, you are right. Following your corrections, the above expression can be written as, $$\dfrac{d\left(V\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}{ d\left(V\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}=
\frac{sin(\theta)dV + V cos(\theta)d\theta}{cos(\theta)dV - V sin(\theta)d\theta} = 
\frac{tan(\theta)(\frac{dV}{V}) + d\theta}{(\frac{dV}{V})-tan(\theta)d\theta}$$ This equation is slightly similar to the one found in the material: https://montoguequiz.com/mechanical/prandtl-meyer-expansion-waves/

Comment: Have you been able to proceed further and obtain the sought equation? Or do you need further help?

Comment: Hello YNk, Yes I solved this some minutes ago.

$$ \frac{d(Vsin(\theta))}{d(Vcos(\theta))} = \frac{sin(\theta)dV + V cos(\theta)d\theta}{cos(\theta)dV - V sin(\theta)d\theta)} $$

$$ \frac{sin(\theta)dV + V cos(\theta)d\theta}{cos(\theta)dV - V sin(\theta)d\theta)} = \frac{M^{2}sin(\theta)cos(\theta)\mp \sqrt{M^{2}-1}}{1-M^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)} $$

Comment: For the two characteristic lines at 0 and 90 degrees,
$$if (\theta = 0)$$
$$\frac{Vd\theta}{dV} = \mp \sqrt{M^{2}-1}$$
$$d\theta =  \mp \sqrt{M^{2}-1} \frac{dV}{V}$$

$$if (\theta = 90)$$
$$\frac{dV}{-Vd\theta} = \mp \frac{\sqrt{M^{2}-1}}{1-M^{2}}$$
$$d\theta =  \mp \sqrt{M^{2}-1} \frac{dV}{V}$$ Thank you for your help YNK. You gave me a lead to complete this task.

Comment: Well, I thought you wanted to solve this problem for any $\theta$, not just for $\theta =0$ and $\theta = 90$.  If you want to, you can show that the given equation holds for any $\theta$.